# Django custom model manager

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

If we have model like

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.IntegerField()
    field_2 = models.IntegerField()
```

and in every query for a given `value` if we have to check against both the fields, is it possible to simplify the redundancy (`field_1=value, field_2=value`) using a custom `Manager` ?

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(Q(field_1=value) | Q(field_2=value))
SomeModel.objects.filter(Q(field_1=value) | Q(field_2=value)).count()
```

Comment: Given you each time need to do that, is there a situation where `field_1` and `field_2` have a different value?

Comment: Good catch. No they will never be the same and its the `or` condition instead of `and`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can make a mananger, like:

```
class SomeModelManager(models.Manager):

    def with_value(self, value):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(field_1=value, field_2=value)
```

or with an or-condition:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class SomeModelManager(models.Manager):

    def with_value(self, value):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(Q(field_1=value) | Q(field_2=value)
```

We can then add the manager to the `SomeModel` model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.IntegerField()
    field_2 = models.IntegerField()

    object = SomeModelManager()
```

Then you can access the filtered queryset with:

```
SomeModel.objects.with_value(value)
SomeModel.objects.with_value(value).count()
```